# Disallow /*foo but allow /*bar?foo=foo (i.e. how to disallow an API if query string might contain the same name?)

Tags: robots.txt

I want to disallow `/*foo` endpoint regardless of its query string, but allow `/*bar` regardless of its query string.

A robots.txt like below would also disallow `/*bar?foo=foo` with query string or with higher path which contains `foo` such as `/foo/bar`.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:   /*foo
```

How should I set robots.txt in this case? Does putting `$` at the end work in this scenario?

The "standard" robots.txt doesn't accept wildcards, so I'm talking about the ones like used by Google.